# Dropping columns on a dataframe based on their count of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

Hi I am new to pandas and struggling with a manipulation.
I have a dataframe df with a huge number of columns, and I only want to keep the number of columns that have a count of above 5000 values.

I tried the loop below but it does not work. Is there any easy way to do this? Also is there a function I could create to apply this to any dataframe where I want to keep columns with only n values or more?

```
for column in df.columns: 
   if df[column].count() > 5000: 
      column = column
   else: 
      df[column].drop()
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "count"? You mean non NaN values? So non-missing values?

Comment: yes, non NaN values. So for instance when you do df.describe() i want to filter out all those columns that have less than 5000 in count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [`DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) which has the argument `thresh`, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': [4, 5, np.nan],
    'C': [np.nan, np.nan, 6],
    'D': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
})


   A    B    C   D
0  1  4.0  NaN NaN
1  2  5.0  NaN NaN
2  3  NaN  6.0 NaN
```

We set the threshold to `2`, in your case it is `5000`:

```
df.dropna(thresh=2, axis=1)

   A    B
0  1  4.0
1  2  5.0
2  3  NaN
```

Notice column `C` and `D` dropped because they had less than 2 non-Na values

Comment: thanks! this works perfectly, although according to the documentation tresh = requirement from non-Na values. So C and D dropped because they had less than 2 non-Na values

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newdf=df.copy()
for column in newdf.columns: 
    if df[column].count() <= 5000: 
        df=df.drop(column, axis=1)
```

or the equivalent:

```
newdf=df.copy()
for column in newdf.columns: 
    if df[column].count() <= 5000: 
        del df.column
```

Comment: thanks for helping but it's not working fully. The second one does not run and the first one runs but when I try to view the df in the next cell it makes the notebook crash one out of two times. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Maybe it's because we are looping and deleting items at the same time. I added a version with loop over a copy of the df, can you please try again?

Comment: it's still quite slow. the first solution definitely works but it's very slow!